# Do we have accepted terms for semigroups and semigroupoids without identities?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, semigroups

I would like to call a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) without an identity a "pure semigroup" and a [semigroupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroupoid) without any identity a "pure semigroupoid". I'm not sure whether such things have been defined in literature before so may I ask whether accepted terms for such things already exist..thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) is just a set with an associative binary relation, not necessarily with identity. A semigroup with identity is called a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

Comment: Seems that OP is already aware of it. The question was about how to call a semigroup, which is not a monoid.

Comment: Yes I want to see whether there is an established term for a semigroup that is strictly free from an identity..That means...a semigroup S such that for all elements $x\in S$ there exists a $y\in S$ such that $xy \neq y$ or $yx\neq y$.

Comment: @YingZhou: I think your best bet is "semigroup without identity". Unless you use this term multiple times, in which case you are looking for an abbreviation. But I don't think there is a universally established terminology. You have to make up your own.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos Thank you very much! I will use this term multiple times.

Comment: Perhaps a shorter one: *unitless semigroup*